# a makefile for a driver doesnt accept spaces in the path, how to fix that?

Tags: makefile

I am trying to fix a makefile so it works even if you have it in a path with spaces (a folder which this is in has a space in it) and I cant figure it out

I tried adding quotes in many combinations and searching for the TopDIR code but I cannot find anything helpful

here is the source code with the makefile
https://github.com/uzh-rpg/rpg_dwa171_wifidongle.git

the problem seems to be here, this code gets TopDIR but if there is a space in a folder in the path it results in an error.

```
########### HAL_RTL8821C #################################
ifeq ($(CONFIG_RTL8821C), y)
include $(TopDIR)/rtl8821c.mk #<-line 824#
endif
```

expected is to run the make process and it runs if there is no space in the folders

but with spaces you get this error:

```
Makefile:824: drivers/rpg_dwa171_wifidongle/rtl8821c.mk: No such file or directory
make: *** No rule to make target 'drivers/rpg_dwa171_wifidongle/rtl8821c.mk'.  Stop.
```

here a folder named "wifi drivers" breaks the code

Answer (score 0):

Spaces within include could be escaped with backslash. For example,

```
space := $(space) #
include $(subst $(space),\$(space),$(TopDir))/rtl8821c.mk
```